# Using A CTE with a left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have an exiting query with a structure:

```
With As MainQuery(.....)
     As Sub 1 (.....)
     As Sub 2 (.....)
     As Sub 3 (.....)
select.....
```

I now need to join the results from this query to another query I have, so I want to left join it to the other query..
like this:

```
left join (
select * from (
With As MainQuery(.....)
     As Sub 1 (.....)
     As Sub 2 (.....)
     As Sub 3 (.....)
select.....) as results
```

I keep getting errors. not sure if this is possible or which other methods can I use.

Thank you

Comment: Post your actual queries. You have a CTE, not a WITH clause. A CTE is equivalent to a subquery in most cases. It acts like a subquery definition that can be used later in the query. Most likely, you can put your CTEs at the top of your new query and use them.

Comment: Instead of trying to put the old query "under" the new one, change the final part of your old query to JOIN with the new query. Or convert that final part into a CTE as well, and use the new query in its place

Comment: The keyword `AS` goes *after* the name, not before it, ie `WITH myCTE AS (SELECT …), ` etc

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the documenation [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which includes [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-creating-a-simple-common-table-expression) of how to use them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, a <WITH clause> is the formal ANSI/ISO SQL term for what many call cte. (Feature T121, “WITH (excluding RECURSIVE ) in query expression”)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any exceptions as to why this won't work. But all you have to do is move your CTE's to the top of the main query.

In this particular example, since your sub-query is not correlated (the subquery is not accessing any fields in the outside query, it's simply returning a dataset). Then you can just move the CTE's to the top, like this:

```sql
-- Generate list of numbers 1-9, then select top 5 randomly
WITH c1 AS (SELECT x.x FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1)) x(x))
    , c2(x) AS (SELECT 1 FROM c1 x CROSS JOIN c1 y)
    , c3(n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c2.x) FROM c2)
SELECT TOP(5) x.n
FROM c3 x
ORDER BY NEWID();

-- All numbers 1-9
SELECT x.n
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) x(n)
```

Say I have these two queries. I want to `LEFT JOIN` my query with the CTE's into my second query. So that way I have all numbers 1-9, on the left, and then I can see which numbers are missing from the right.

Just move your `SELECT` statement to the `LEFT JOIN` subquery, and you can still reference your CTE's:

```sql
WITH c1 AS (SELECT x.x FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1)) x(x))
    , c2(x) AS (SELECT 1 FROM c1 x CROSS JOIN c1 y)
    , c3(n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c2.x) FROM c2)
SELECT x.n, z.n
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) x(n)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT TOP(5) x.n
        FROM c3 x
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    ) z ON z.n = x.n
```

Now, if you were trying to use something that references outside the subquery, like a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` list, or an `OUTER/CROSS APPLY` or maybe an `EXISTS()` clause, that's different. But in this case, if it's not correlated, then simply moving it to the top *should* work just fine.